# shell script to download latest file from FTP

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I am writing shell script first time, I want to download latest create file from FTP.
I want to download latest file of specific folder. Below is my code for that. But it is downloading all the files of the folder not the latest one.

```
ftp -in ftp.abc.com << SCRIPTEND
user xyz xyz
binary
cd Rpts/
mget ls -t -r | tail -n 1
quit
SCRIPTEND
```

help me with this, please?

Comment: See also [Get the latest file from a remote server from an FTP in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28835893/850848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using wget or lftp utility instead, it compares file time/date and AFAIR its purpose is ftp scripting. Switch to ssh/rsync if possible, you can read a bit about lftp instead of rsync here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Probably the easiest way is to link last version on server side to "current", and always get the file pointed. If you're not admin of the server, you need to list all files with date/time, grab the information, parse it, decide which one is newest, in the meantime state on the server can change, and you find yourself in more complicated solution than it's worth.

The point is, that "ls" sorts output in some way, and time may not be default. There are switches to sort it e.g. base on modification time, however even when server responds with OK on ls -t , you can't be sure it really supports sorting, it can just ignore all switches and always return the same list, that's why admins usually use "current" link (ln -s). If there's no "current", to make sure you have the right file, you need to parse list anyway ( ls -al ).

http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/unix-koans/shell-tools.html

Comment: hey,could you please provide me the code..as i am new to this

Comment: I have seen that.. but those are the codes to download from FTP..but i  can do that with this script as well..But the prob is to download latest file

Comment: the ls command I have used is do exactly the same thing to grab the latest file name..but i dont kn why it is not working in case of ftp

Comment: so by your latest update.. i mean that i have to list all the files and find the latest file using some logic.. But can't i have script similar to i mentioned?

Comment: You can, of course, but I tell you, that the concept is wrong by design, and will never work "fine", and your work will be classic "piece of great, well-done, unnecessary work" :) Please elaborate more on what purpose the whole thing is intended to, I bet you push in wrong direction. What's the file, what it's going to be used for?

Comment: in tht folder our manager will place the report file everyday.. Hence currently, I am using a ftp client to connect and download the latest report file. But Now i want to make script of it..such that it should be easy just to execute script only..

Comment: alright, what about including the date like 2012-09-18-report.txt in the filename, and simply get the file with current day? Does the filename differs each time? Can't you predict on client side, from the filename and date, what will be the name of newest report on server side?

Comment: retrieving and parsing dates/times of creation/modification in full filelist will be the worst of possible solutions, I tell you. :)

Comment: the name of the file will not be fixed.. as the manager is making filename with different type of name and cant ask him to specify filename with specific format... When I started I guess it is simple process but I got stuck with this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16823/discussion-between-piotr-wadas-and-mahesh)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, the line

`mget ls -t -r | tail -n 1`

doesn't do what you think. It actually grabs all of the output of `ls -t` and then `tail` processes the output of `mget`. You could replace this line with

`mget $(ls -t -r | tail -n 1)`

but I am not sure if `ftp` will support such a call...

Try using an FTP client other than `ftp`. For example, `curlftpfs` available at [curlftpfs.sourceforge.net](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) is a good candidate as it allows you to mount an FTP to a directory as if it is a local folder and then run different commands on the files there (including find, grep, etc.). [Take a look at this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/594).

This way, since the output comes form a local command, you'd be more certain that `ls -t` returns a properly sorted list.

Btw, it's a bit less convoluted to use `ls -t | head -1` than `ls -t -r | tail -1`. They produce the same result but why reverse and grab from the tail when you can just grab the head :)

If you use curlftpfs then your script would be something like this (assuming server ftp.abc.com and user xyz with password xyz).

```
mkdir /tmp/ftpsession
curlftpfs ftp://xyz:xyz@ftp.abc.com /tmp/ftpsession
cd /tmp/ftpsession/Rpts
cp -Rpf $(ls -t | head -1) /your/destination/folder/or/file
cd -
umount /tmp/ftpsession
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on curlftpfs!

Answer (score 1):

My Solution is this:

```
curl 'ftp://server.de/dir/'$(curl 'ftp://server.de/dir/' 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | awk '{print $(NF)}')
```