# Get the latest file from a remote server from an FTP in Unix

Tags: unix, ftp

I need to get a file from a remote host in Unix. I am using the `ftp` command. The issue is I need the latest file from that location. This is how I am doing it:

```
dir=/home/user/nyfolders
latest_file=$(ls  *abc.123.* | tail -1)
ftp -nv <<EOF
open $hostname
user $username $password
binary
cd $dir
get $latest_file
bye
EOF
```

But I get this error:

```
(remote-file) usage: get remote-file [ local-file ]
```

I think the way I am trying to get the file from within the `ftp` command is incorrect, can someone please help me out?

Comment: You are downloading to unix too?

Comment: @shellter The `lastest_file` is not a file, it's an environment variable. He tries to use `ls` and `tail` from `ftp` script to find out the name of the latest file. That cannot work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use shell features, like aliases, piping, variables, etc, in `ftp` command script.

The `ftp` does not support such advanced features using any syntax.

Though, you can do it two-step (to make use of shell features between the steps).

First get a listing of remote directory to a local file (`/tmp/listing.txt`):

```
ftp -nv <<EOF
open $hostname
user $username $password
cd $dir
nlist *abc.123.* /tmp/listing.txt
bye
EOF
```

Find the latest file:

```
latest_file=`tail -1 /tmp/listing.txt`
```

And download it:

```
ftp -nv <<EOF
open $hostname
user $username $password
binary
cd $dir
get $latest_file
bye
EOF
```

Comment: The first part of the script(getting the latest file) works as expected. But in order to get the file when I do the second ftp, I get this error: `550 -rw-rw-r--: No such file or directory`. If I do a ls or even ls -lA, I see its listing entries starting with "." and ".." Is there any way I can ignore these entries and just get the files? Thanks!

Comment: 1) To solve the first problem, use `nlist` instead of `ls`. See my updated answer. 2) I suppose the second question is not related to the topic, right? Anyway, what about  `grep -v ^.+$ /tmp/listing.txt`

Comment: thanks Martin! I solved the it. The issue was, it was getting the latest file from the listing file, but that included the full directory of the file along with the permissions on it, which it was trying to "get". So it was looking for a file name "-rw-rw..." I had to do some parsing to get just the file name, excluding every other info and then do a get with that.

Comment: Btw, with nlist, I dont have to do all that parsing at all. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I suppose, nlist -t should be used to get sorted list

Comment: @ValentinaChumak The FTP commands have no switches. Some FTP servers do support them though. But it's non standard. You can use it only if your server does. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36035384/850848