# ftp latest file from remote to local

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ftp

I have written a shell script to ftp a remote file to local server. But Its giving me error.
Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/local-path
HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
binary
user $USER $PASSWD
cd /home/server-path
theFile=$(ls -t | head -n 1)
get $theFile
bye
EOT
```

When running I am getting below error:

```
Connected to server.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
250 Directory successfully changed.
?Invalid command
(remote-file) (local-file)
221 Goodbye.
```

If I hard code complete file path instead of *cd /home/server-path* & *theFile=$(ls -t | head -n 1)*, it works fine. Problem is I dont know the exact remote file name, as there are multiple file, and I only need to ftp latest one.

Could you please review and tell me what error I am making here, thanks.

Comment: `theFile=$(ls -t | head -n 1)` is not valid FTP syntax. That's `bash` syntax, which is completely different. The easiest solution will probably be to make two connections - one to run `ls -t` so you can parse the output of the session, and a second to actually get the file that you parsed out. Alternatively, you could run FTP as a coprocess, but that's more complex and fragile, and difficult to get right...

Comment: ls -t is not a valid ftp command. You can refer to the answer over this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835893/get-the-latest-file-from-a-remote-server-from-an-ftp-in-unix

Answer (score -1):

The FTP which I work with only supports a few commands. So basically you can use the `get` command to put the file from the FTP to your directory. Better put all the files from remote directory to the local and then use `ls -t | head -n1` in the local directory to get the latest file.

**Here is the code:**

```
!/bin/bash
path=/some/path

export path
echo   "-----------Downloading the file from SFTP Location----------------"

cd "$path"
sftp -b /dev/stdin user@host <<CMDS
cd [remote-directory path]
pwd
get allfilenames local-directory
bye
CMDS
cd "$path"
ls -t | head -n1
```